# Why does China propose to build a community with a shared future for mankind?

Tags: china, foreign-policy, globalization

It is a very possible trend for all forces on the earth to unite, but at present it will not happen in the short term, and it is more likely to happen when the earth resists foreign enemies than spontaneous unity of human beings.

Why is China proposing to [build a community with a shared future for mankind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_of_Common_Destiny) at this time? (The [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_of_Common_Destiny) contains errors and many omissions. You can try to translate the  [Chinese Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%BA%E7%B1%BB%E5%91%BD%E8%BF%90%E5%85%B1%E5%90%8C%E4%BD%93) into English.)

What does China want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: What exactly their motivations are, besides what they communicate, is likely not all that knowable.  But [The Avoidable War: The Dangers of a Catastrophic Conflict between the US and Xi Jinping's China](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/57432319) claims that China wants to refashion the world order more to its liking by adding new, China-origin elements to the world institutions.  Look at your own link: *“Building a community of common destiny for mankind is the overall goal of China's foreign affairs work in the new era” and requires a “**new type of international relations.**”[24]*

Comment: That's on the cynical, Western end of opinion.  A more pro-China opinion will point out the great benefits of these changes and the welcome relief from Western-led world unipolarity.  Ultimately the motivations for this are a matter of opinion, unless one wants to take their claims at face value.

Comment: Umm . . . . because it sounds better than "we're going to conquer the world until everyone and everything revolves around Beijing" in a press release? Even then, it sounds pretty creepy and echos historic creepy Chinese sphere of influence foreign policy agendas. I have serious doubts about whether this is an answerable question. But let's see what happens.

Comment: "it is more likely to happen when the earth resists foreign enemies" *War of the Worlds* - *Independence Day* - space alien invasion political theory? Really?

Comment: @ohwilleke I don’t know what will happen at a specific time in the future, but alien civilization theoretically exists. And with each country focused on its own interests right now, it’s hard to imagine China’s appeals having a literal effect.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Your point of view is indeed very philosophical. Although it is easy for ordinary people to accept China's point of view, because if human beings can unite, the world may be better, but in fact the pattern constructed by this point of view is almost impossible to realize unless the world undergoes very significant changes.

Comment: "What does China want to achieve by doing this?" Looking as of they were the good guys, I guess. Note that there are not many details about the plan available or that China itself commits to anything. Surely it doesn't mean that China wants to become a liberal democracy anytime soon.

Comment: This question appears meaningless until we know what a "community with a shared future for mankind" is. Your link doesn't explain that. Without that information it's a bit like asking why someone wants world peace and happiness. (Why they have made the announcement now might be a more valid question, but it seems the sort of fluff the Chinese government comes out with from time to time.)

Comment: @StuartF My bad.Try the translated Chinese Wikipedia. The content of the English Wikipedia produces considerable deviations and omissions.

Answer (score 7):

It is a political slogan with no substance.

The Chinese Communist Party is trying to build a "Community of Common Destiny for Mankind" no more than Imperial Japan was trying to build a "[Greater East Asia Co-Prosperity Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_East_Asia_Co-Prosperity_Sphere)".

Comment: I think using an enemy with a blood feud to smear a country does not seem like an appropriate answer, more like unprovoked hatred. But I believe it might be a better answer if you could give a more detailed explanation. Japan uses beautiful visions to cover up ugly crimes against humanity. This is the purpose of Japan's launch of this slogan. Can you elaborate on what China hopes to achieve by calling on this slogan?

Comment: Aren't they all? I don't own an hypocriticalometer, but I don't think this chinese initiative is any less cynical than the US [good neighbour policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Neighbor_policy) or the current "rules-based order".

Comment: *"It is a political slogan with no substance."* - and so is this answer. If you want to insinuate that China isn't serious about this or even has nefarious motives, then you need some serious proof for that. Without, this is really just slander against a specific country.

Comment: @Jack_here This comparison is very apt. Indeed, China's slogan was probably inspired by Japan's earlier slogan.

Comment: @Philipp: It should be up to users here to decide the worth of each answer. And not up to an individual mod here to simply delete an answer because he doesn't like it. If you don't like an answer, you're free to downvote it just like everyone else. Deleting an answer just because you don't like it is an abuse of your power.

Comment: I think this is not a rigorous answer, please refer to the next answer.